# Server/client application error

Tags: python, sockets

sir i am developing server client program in python. when i try to run the client it gives me an error, saying

clientSocket.sendto(message, addr)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

what is the possible reson for this.? how to pass it as a bytes strings? any help would be highly aprriciated

```
import time
from socket import *

for pings in range(10):
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
clientSocket.settimeout(1)
message = 'test'
addr = ("127.0.0.1", 12000)

start = time.time()
clientSocket.sendto(message, addr)
try:
    data, server = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    print ("%s %d %d") % (data, pings, elapsed)
except timeout:
    print ("REQUEST TIMED OUT")
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: python 3 sir, thnks sir i have figured it out

Answer (score 0):

clientSocket.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), addr)